# Can't finish regexp

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build regexp for finding valid names in mmorpg game. Here's the rules:

1. Must be at least 4 characters.
2. Cannot exceed 24 characters.
3. May contain the characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and single quotation. (Corporation names may also include minus and dot characters.)
4. Space or single quotation characters are not allowed as the first or last character in a name.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
/([A-z0-9]{1}[A-z0-9]{3,23}[A-z0-9]{1})$/
```

The problem is I can't insert zero or one quotation and zero or more spaces inside {3,23} part. Any tips?

Comment: You could have been done by now just using conditional statements hahahaha! Wish I could help, my knowledge of RegEx is very limited, though it is a very useful language I've found!""""""

Comment: If you want your program to run faster and be easier to maintain - implement each one of the rules as a separate validation-method and try to avoid using regex as much as possible!

Comment: The extra benefit of using separate rules is that you can tell the user exactly what's wrong with the name they picked.

Comment: @alfasin I strongly disagree, this is precisely the kind of problems regex are supposed to solve.

Comment: What about the spaces? Do they could towards the character limit?

Comment: @roflomglol Okay, I have put back my previous answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9](?!([^']*'){2})[ A-Za-z0-9'.-]{2,22}[A-Za-z0-9]$/
```

btw `[A-z]` is not same as `[A-Za-z]` as range from `A` to `z` will allow many more characters.

#### [Online regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nQ9mJ4/2)

Comment: @anubhava sorry for late answer. Actually, your regexp doesn't catch "zero or more spaces". Try to add more than one and you will see. P.S. ordered requirements are vague, yes. But I clearly said that zero or one quotation and zero or more spaces.

Comment: Did you see 3rd input in my demo which is `Name Surname` and allows only 1 space.

Comment: In the same demo you will see an input `Name Surname Name` with 2 spaced and it is not matched.

Comment: @anubhava Sorry I don't seem to follow you. I need 0-N spaces and 0-1 single quotations. Your regexp while blocking more than one quotation doesn't allow more than one space. It should be legal to set name "Jesus Mary Joseph".

Comment: ok I though you wanted to allow only 1 space. I have just edited it to allow N spaces now.

Comment: Also I believe `'abc` is not a valid input which is allowed by other answer but not mine.

Comment: Didn't you have this requirement: **Space or single quotation characters are not allowed as the first or last character in a name.**

Comment: You are right. Didn't check that. Corrected version of yours suits me well. Could you please explain your regexp?

Comment: Sorry just came back online. The demo link I provided has detailed explanation of this regex in the top right section. Just go through it once and let me know if you have any follow up question afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this regex

```
^(?=.{4,24}$)(?=[^']*'?[^']*$)(?![ ']|.*[ ']$)[A-Za-z0-9'. -]+$
```

`(?=.{4,24}$)` is for the character limit

`(?=[^']*'?[^']*$)` is for the optional one apostrophe character (note `"` is more known as quote character than `'`).

`(?![ ']|.*[ ']$)` prevents spaces and apostrophes at the beginning and end.

`[A-Za-z0-9'. -]+$` allows alphanumeric, apostrophe (already restricted to 1 by an earlier lookahead), dashes, dots and spaces (any number).'

Comment: That works good! Thanks, and additional thanks for explaining this. :)

Comment: @roflomglol the other answer doesn't accept dot at the beginning or at the end while mine does as required